# Why does the UnboundLocalError get raised on this code?

Tags: python, debugging

I am creating a computer login code that will lock you out after an amount of faults. 
But the code returns the `UnboundLocalError` on the `attempts` variable.
I have made `attempts` global but it hasn't changed anything. It is raised on

```
if (user == username) and (passwd == password):
    `print("You are logged on")`
else:
    attempts += 1
    if attempts == 3:
        print("You have been locked out of your computer")
        time.sleep(60)
```

All of this is in a function and attempts is made `global`.
Can someone help?

Comment: You should provide more details about your code, with that little information it is hard to provide you any help.

Comment: This code would raise a `NameError`, not an `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: can you please share the code snippet so that the problem can be looked upon!

Comment: "and attempts is made global" No, it isn't. If it were, `global` would appear *in this part of the code*.